# HowTo allow Role testing AWS API Gateway with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

I'm currently stuck on a permission problem with AWS/Terraform. I've created a test CRUD Lambda/API Gateway, including custom domain:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "role_lambda_exec" {
  name = "role_lambda_exec"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
    "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "delete_test" {
  filename         = "./build/placeholder.zip"
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("./build/placeholder.zip")
  function_name    = "delete_test"
  role             = aws_iam_role.role_lambda_exec.arn
  handler          = "placeholder"
  runtime          = "go1.x"
  timeout          = 60
  publish          = true

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      "last_modified",
      "qualified_arn",
      "source_code_hash",
      "version"
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "get_test" {
  filename         = "./build/placeholder.zip"
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("./build/placeholder.zip")
  function_name    = "get_test"
  role             = aws_iam_role.role_lambda_exec.arn
  handler          = "placeholder"
  runtime          = "go1.x"
  timeout          = 60
  publish          = true

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      "last_modified",
      "qualified_arn",
      "source_code_hash",
      "version"
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "patch_test" {
  filename         = "./build/placeholder.zip"
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("./build/placeholder.zip")
  function_name    = "patch_test"
  role             = aws_iam_role.role_lambda_exec.arn
  handler          = "placeholder"
  runtime          = "go1.x"
  timeout          = 60
  publish          = true

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      "last_modified",
      "qualified_arn",
      "source_code_hash",
      "version"
    ]
  }
}
resource "aws_lambda_function" "post_test" {
  filename         = "./build/placeholder.zip"
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("./build/placeholder.zip")
  function_name    = "post_test"
  role             = aws_iam_role.role_lambda_exec.arn
  handler          = "placeholder"
  runtime          = "go1.x"
  timeout          = 60
  publish          = true

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      "last_modified",
      "qualified_arn",
      "source_code_hash",
      "version"
    ]
  }
}
resource "aws_lambda_function" "put_test" {
  filename         = "./build/placeholder.zip"
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("./build/placeholder.zip")
  function_name    = "put_test"
  role             = aws_iam_role.role_lambda_exec.arn
  handler          = "placeholder"
  runtime          = "go1.x"
  timeout          = 60
  publish          = true

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      "last_modified",
      "qualified_arn",
      "source_code_hash",
      "version"
    ]
  }
}

data "template_file" "openapi" {
  template = file("openapi.yaml")
  vars     = {
    title                 = var.service_name_test
    description           = var.service_description_test
    server_testing_url    = var.service_url_test
    server_production_url = var.service_url_test
    delete_arn            = aws_lambda_function.delete_test.invoke_arn
    get_arn               = aws_lambda_function.get_test.invoke_arn
    patch_arn             = aws_lambda_function.patch_test.invoke_arn
    post_arn              = aws_lambda_function.post_test.invoke_arn
    put_arn               = aws_lambda_function.put_test.invoke_arn
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "rest_api_test" {
  name        = var.service_name_test
  description = var.service_description_test
  body        = data.template_file.openapi.rendered

  endpoint_configuration {
    types = ["REGIONAL"]
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "deployment_test" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api_test.id
  stage_name  = var.stage_name_test
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_domain_name" "domain_name_test" {
  domain_name              = var.service_domain_test
  regional_certificate_arn = var.cert_arn_domain
  security_policy          = "TLS_1_2"

  endpoint_configuration {
    types = ["REGIONAL"]
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_base_path_mapping" "base_path_mapping_test" {
  domain_name = var.service_domain_test
  api_id      = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api_test.id
  stage_name  = var.stage_name_test
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "route53_record_test" {
  type    = "A"
  name    = var.service_domain_test
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.route53_zone_domain.id

  alias {
    evaluate_target_health = true
    name                   = aws_api_gateway_domain_name.domain_name_test.regional_domain_name
    zone_id                = aws_api_gateway_domain_name.domain_name_test.regional_zone_id
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "apigateway_lambda_invoke_delete_test" {
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.delete_test.arn
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "${aws_api_gateway_deployment.deployment_test.execution_arn}/*/*"
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "apigateway_lambda_invoke_get_test" {
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.get_test.arn
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "${aws_api_gateway_deployment.deployment_test.execution_arn}/*/*"
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "apigateway_lambda_invoke_patch_test" {
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.patch_test.arn
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "${aws_api_gateway_deployment.deployment_test.execution_arn}/*/*"
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "apigateway_lambda_invoke_post_test" {
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.post_test.arn
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "${aws_api_gateway_deployment.deployment_test.execution_arn}/*/*"
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "apigateway_lambda_invoke_put_test" {
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.put_test.arn
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "${aws_api_gateway_deployment.deployment_test.execution_arn}/*/*"
}
```

While the CRUD (API) is working as expected (curl/insomia). Now I'm trying to pass policies to a role for testing (invoke) lambda and API Gateway, while the first part (allow the role to invoke lambda) was quite  easy, with the second part (test API Gateway) I'm getting crazy:

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}

// new role developers, should allowed to manual trigger api-gateway and lambda tests

resource "aws_iam_role" "developers" {
  name = "developers"
  max_session_duration = "43200"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
    "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:saml-provider/simplesamlphp"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithSAML",
      "Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
      "SAML:aud": "https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml"
    }
      }
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

data "aws_iam_policy" "ReadOnlyAccess" {
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/ReadOnlyAccess"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "role_read_only_access" {
  policy_arn = data.aws_iam_policy.ReadOnlyAccess.arn
  role = aws_iam_role.developers.name
}

// allow developers to test lambda functions

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "role_lambda_invoke_get_test" {
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.get_test.arn
  principal     = aws_iam_role.developers.arn
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "role_lambda_invoke_delete_test" {
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.delete_test.arn
  principal     = aws_iam_role.developers.arn
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "role_lambda_invoke_patch_test" {
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.patch_test.arn
  principal     = aws_iam_role.developers.arn
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "role_lambda_invoke_post_test" {
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.post_test.arn
  principal     = aws_iam_role.developers.arn
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "role_lambda_invoke_put_test" {
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.put_test.arn
  principal     = aws_iam_role.developers.arn
}

data "aws_region" "current" {}

// this should allow testing api gateway trigger the lambda functions, but BROKEN!!!

resource "aws_iam_policy" "apigateway_invoke" {
  name = "apigateway_invoke"
  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Statement":[
    {
        "Effect":"Allow",
        "Action":[
            "apigateway:*"
        ],
        "Resource":[
            "arn:aws:apigateway:${data.aws_region.current.name}::/restapis/${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api_test.id}",
            "arn:aws:apigateway:${data.aws_region.current.name}::/restapis/${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api_test.id}/*"
        ]
    }
    ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "apigateway_invoke" {
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.apigateway_invoke.arn
  role = aws_iam_role.developers.name
}
```

The log told me, that invalid permissions on lambda exist, but i don't see it....

```
Execution log for request b6f095a2-bbac-11e9-80e2-23b77a1af624
Sat Aug 10 20:23:28 UTC 2019 : Starting execution for request: b6f095a2-bbac-11e9-80e2-23b77a1af624
Sat Aug 10 20:23:28 UTC 2019 : HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /test
Sat Aug 10 20:23:28 UTC 2019 : Method request path: {uuid=test}
Sat Aug 10 20:23:28 UTC 2019 : Method request query string: {}
Sat Aug 10 20:23:28 UTC 2019 : Method request headers: {}
Sat Aug 10 20:23:28 UTC 2019 : Method request body before transformations: 
Sat Aug 10 20:23:28 UTC 2019 : Endpoint request URI: https://lambda.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:function:get_test/invocations
Sat Aug 10 20:23:28 UTC 2019 : Endpoint request headers: {x-amzn-lambda-integration-tag=b6f095a2-bbac-11e9-80e2-23b77a1af624, Authorization=***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************65b8da, X-Amz-Date=20190810T202328Z, x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=9uzhf3d0od, X-Amz-Source-Arn=arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:9uzhf3d0od/test-invoke-stage/GET/{uuid}, Accept=application/json, User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_9uzhf3d0od, X-Amz-Security-Token=AgoJb3JpZ2luX2VjECQaDGV1LWNlbnRyYWwtMSJIMEYCIQCfeL4YSUD8FjtyeEI2VRf/aofAdtm7/p29yzrbudB0+AIhAPjcgFav7vzo4i2te4p6KFViSuXUpirgCw4vE/VxCVanKukDCK3//////////wEQARoMNDc0MjQwMTQ2ODAyIgy/cIQQylFZ568eqJMqvQP861i5/+YeL9kCJLYoXqIwEsKJk0XKAmRPFMSvUb6AKBIUyUA2qjuaINkFqmOMagOJpWIZmvuOPyN1oweywfUsRndil5HmnBoThu3SPdJUp/TaTpgu0UMKTqRivZ3FwHFF+a8cND9P [TRUNCATED]
Sat Aug 10 20:23:28 UTC 2019 : Endpoint request body after transformations: {"resource":"/{uuid}","path":"/test","httpMethod":"GET","headers":null,"multiValueHeaders":null,"queryStringParameters":null,"multiValueQueryStringParameters":null,"pathParameters":{"uuid":"test"},"stageVariables":null,"requestContext":{"resourceId":"6yd4vs","resourcePath":"/{uuid}","operationName":"get","httpMethod":"GET","extendedRequestId":"eOMmJFuJFiAFrPg=","requestTime":"10/Aug/2019:20:23:28 +0000","path":"/{uuid}","accountId":"XXXXXXXXXXX","protocol":"HTTP/1.1","stage":"test-invoke-stage","domainPrefix":"testPrefix","requestTimeEpoch":1565468608953,"requestId":"b6f095a2-bbac-11e9-80e2-23b77a1af624","identity":{"cognitoIdentityPoolId":null,"cognitoIdentityId":null,"apiKey":"test-invoke-api-key","principalOrgId":null,"cognitoAuthenticationType":null,"userArn":"arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/developers/uid","apiKeyId":"test-invoke-api-key-id","userAgent":"aws-internal/3 aws-sdk-java/1.11.590 Linux/4.9.137-0.1.ac.218.74.329.metal1.x86_64 OpenJDK_64-Bit_S [TRUNCATED]
Sat Aug 10 20:23:28 UTC 2019 : Sending request to https://lambda.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:function:get_test/invocations
Sat Aug 10 20:23:28 UTC 2019 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid permissions on Lambda function
Sat Aug 10 20:23:28 UTC 2019 : Method completed with status: 500
```

I'm running out of ideas... :-(

Answer (score 1):

After i've created a method via gui, a dialog for permission is shown and then the testing and api call for this method works. so took a look into the policy and saw the mistake after some minutes.... the source arn was wrong, i've used the deployment arn but i have to use the rest_api arn

```
### wrong
source_arn = "${aws_api_gateway_deployment.deployment_test.execution_arn}/*/*"

### correct
source_arn = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.rest_api_test.execution_arn}/*/*"
```

Answer (score 0):

To invoke an AWS API Gateway resource, you should have `"execute-api:Invoke"` action allowed in your AWS IAM role.

To invoke an AWS Lambda resource, you should have `"lambda:InvokeFunction"` action allowed in your AWS IAM role.

I think you're missing an AWS Lambda invoke permission for the AWS API Gateway service. Check out the code reference for Terraform below.

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "apigw_lambda" {
    statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
    action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
    function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.lambda.function_name}"
    principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
    source_arn = "arn:aws:execute-api:${var.myregion}:${var.accountId}:${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id}/*/${aws_api_gateway_method.method.http_method}${aws_api_gateway_resource.resource.path}"
}
```

Also, you need to update `"apigateway_invoke"` action to `"execute-api:Invoke"` to allow developers to invoke your AWS API Gateway.

Comment: Aren't the resources apigateway_lambda_invoke_[delete|get|patch|post|put]_test should doing exactly this?

also, i've update the api_gateway_rest_api with the following block:


   policy = <<EOF
 {
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [
  {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
      "Resource": "*"
  }
     ]
 }
 EOF


with no luck...

Comment: Try doing the following:
Use the test button in API Gateway to confirm if you can call your Lambda function from within it.
To assess your resource policies, you need to call the GetPolicy API; the execution role controls what your code a do in Lambda, not who can call it. 
You can also turn on logging in API Gateway, which is a good way to gain additional insight into what it's doing on your behalf.

Comment: I've updated the tf file logging lambda/api gateway:

https://gist.github.com/tburschka/a19c6651eb95d172dde5ee58c809284f

While invoke lambda via curl or test button, logs are fine...
But the logs of the API-Gateway is only a lot of empty streams (growing without calls)

=> Use the test button in API Gateway to confirm if you can call your Lambda function from within it. 
Exactly that's what's not working, wile curl works....